# Android linear layout aligning issues

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

What I am trying to do is as below [image]

I tried using linear layout as below

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/widget33"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="#FFFFFF" >
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Eric Lee" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_marginBottom="50px" android:layout_marginTop="10px"></TextView>

  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"> <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/help" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton2"  android:background="@null" android:layout_gravity="left"></ImageButton>
 <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/help" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageButton2"  android:background="@null" android:layout_gravity="top"></ImageButton>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

However i am having trouble  with floating the image left and the right image right. They still stuck at the same Position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/widget33"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1" android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2" android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></ImageButton>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ImageButton02" android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageButton>
        <ImageButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ImageButton01" android:src="@drawable/icon"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageButton>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="match_parent">
        <EditText android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
            <requestFocus></requestFocus>
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hi thx, it solved me issues. may i know why you used relativelayout worked but linearlayout does not work?

Comment: relative layout has property itself to align in left,right. you can do with linear layout also you have to give weight in tht case but if you want to align left right corner something like tht use relative layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_margin="10dp" 
        android:gravity="center">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
     <Button 
     android:id="@+id/Button1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Schedules"/>

     <Button 
      android:id="@+id/Button2"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Button1"
      android:text="Grand Nite"
    />

   <Button
   android:id="@+id/Button3"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@id/Button1"
   android:text="The paper"/>
   <Button
    android:id="@+id/Button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Button3"
    android:layout_below="@id/Button1"
    android:text="The Splash"
   />  

  <Button
  android:id="@+id/Button5"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_below="@id/Button3"
   android:text="Facebook" 
   android:layout_alignRight="@+id/Button4"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```